# How to get reference to the current running Jshell

Tags: java, jshell

I have a file in which I wrote some vars. I want to parse this variables on an runtime application which is opened with the JShell to this instance of Jshell.

FileWithVars.XYZ

```
float x =  5f;
String s = "TestString";
```

Currently I load this file with /o FileWithVars.XYZ in the jshell startup script
But Now I want to do the same thing from the Application which is running in a Jshell.

Any Ideas how to archive that?

Kind Regards

Comment: Can you explain what application and how is it running in Jshell and can that application not parse the file? OR can these variables be not passed as context to the application you're accessing?

Comment: We shall build a gradle Clone in Java with the use of the Jshell.

We have a build.sing file which shall contain all Settings which the user can declare
somethin like
`String srcfolder ="src";`
We wrote a Startup Script which loads our .jar in where all the API is in.
You can go into a empty Folder run the bat which loads all stuff in and open the Jshell. Now you can write init and all needed folder gets created and also the build.sing with standard Settings.

Comment: The idea is to just load the build.sing with /o build.sing and define this variables so we can simple pass them to our constructor.

Thats why we would need to call the /o build.sing from the application to load all the stuff in